# Multipart request without image file

Tags: json, multipartform-data

I want to call multipart service without uploading an image file. It only has input JSON data.
Is it possible to call multipart service with only JSON & file is optional?

Answer (score 0):

it's absolutely possible to make a valid Multipart/form-data request without any files in, yes.

here is a HTTP Post request with multipart/form-data containing only the variable "foo" with the value "bar":

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:9999
User-Agent: curl/7.59.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 141
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------c6d530a086d1167c

--------------------------c6d530a086d1167c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foo"

bar
--------------------------c6d530a086d1167c--
```

generated with the curl command
`curl -F "foo=bar" http://127.0.0.1:9999`